# How Do I remove CSS Grid Header

Tags: html, css, asp.net, web

I would really appreciate some help with this because I have never used the CSS grid before now.  I have the grid configured and it does what I want except there is a large white space at the top which I assume is the header that I don't need to use.  I have been struggling with this problem for some time today.  I've read the similar question and suggested fixes, and nothing works.  I would be done with this page if I can just get rid of the half-inch or so of whitespace above the grid. Below is my CSS class for the grid element.

```css
grid-container {
        left:40px;
        width: 370px;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you, add your HTML as well. Also, keep in mind that when you target classes in css, the class name needs to be preceded by a dot(".").

Comment: Actually, the dot was lost in my cut and paste.  I feel dumb because after leaving the project for a couple of days, I found the problem was not with the grid.  I had a div above with nothing in it but sized.  This pushed the grid down about 70 pixels.  the problem is solved.  Dumb Me!!!!